# MSTest: .testsettings is not always deploying files

Tags: mstest

We have a solution that contains a series of projects used for our tests.  One of those projects contains a set of files that are needed for the tests.  Those files are schemas that will get validated against every time an API route is called.  Tests, naturally, call one or more API routes.

The solution has a `.testsettings` file.  This file has deployment enabled, and it specifies that these schemas need to be deployed.  In addition, every schema file is set to Copy Always.  Also. the `.testsettings` file is in the solution, under Solution Items.

The problem is that the `.testsettings` file is only occasionally respected.  Sometimes the files are copied; sometimes they are not.  When they don't copy, we can do the following to fox it:

- Go to the Test -> Test Settings menu and Choose Select Test Settings
- Select the `.testsettings` file in the solution
- Rebuild the solution
- Rerun the tests

This usually works at least once.  But inevitably, it stops working and the files aren't deployed again.

Note that when you go to the Test -> Test Settings menu, our current `.testsettings` file is always already checked.  So choosing a new `.testsettings` file just means choosing the one that the UI already says is chosen.

We thought of going the `DeploymentItem` route, but this is impractical for a two reasons, surrounding code maintenance.

1. From what I can tell, `DeploymentItem` can only be placed on individual tests. With literally hundreds of tests, we'd be sprinkling it *everywhere*.  It'd become a code maintenance nightmare.  I thought of placing it on the global `TestInitialize` method, but that would just re-copy the files every time a test is run, which seems unnecessary.  Not to mention that I'd have to put literally dozens of `DeploymentItem` attributes on the method and we'd need to keep that up-to-date every time a new schema is added.
2. Related to that, adding new schemas means altering existing tests where necessary.  Again, we have hundreds of tests.

A far better solution would be to have the files copied over once, and then have the code look in the communal pool of schemas whenever it needs one.

I also looked at replacing .testsettings with .runsettings, but it doesn't seem to have a `DeploymentEnabled` node in the XML, and where that option exists it's again specific to `DeploymentEnabled`.

Does anyone have a solution to this, or does anyone know if it's a known bug?  Schema validation happens behind the scenes -- individual test authors don't have to explicitly call it -- and it doesn't fail the test if it doesn't occur (we don't always have schemas available yet for every API call, so we don't want to fail the test if that's the case).  As a result, it's often difficult to immediately ascertain whether or not validation happened.  Because of that, we sometimes get false passes on tests where the schema actually broke, all because the `.testsettings` file didn't actually deploy our files like it's set to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the problem: apparently this issue was fixed in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.  We were using Update 2.  Once we got the new update, this problem went away.